# Factory and Directives with Clientside Database

Tags: angularjs

I have a factory that is loading data to a browser side database.
In the controller I call dataFactory.LoadData() which loads the data successfully.
I need to add a progress bar though.
I have a directive where I can set a progress bar's value changes but I need the factory to either be able to update a scope so I can later update the fields, which it cannot do, or I need the directive updated by the factory. From what I've seen so far, factories are usually passed to the directive and not the other way around. Any ideas how I can get my factory's loading activity to update the controller view?
So the process should be:
1) Factory loads clientside database.
2) While factory module loads to database, show progress bar changes on the view..

Comment: you can use [promise/deferred object](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q) and implement a notify method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achivied through angular's event framework on $scope.

[$emit()](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/%24rootScope.Scope#%24emit) and [$on()](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/%24rootScope.Scope#%24on)

Your factory would need a reference to $scope.  At the appropriate times the factory would use $emit to send an event up the scope that your directive is listening to.  The directive would then update the progress bar.  You can use the args parameter of $emit to send information along with the event.

Factory:

```
factoryMethod() {
  $scope.$emit('my.special.event', args);
}
```

Directive:

```
$scope.$on('my.special.event', function(event, args) {
  //use the event and args to update the progess bar
}
```

Comment: I read that a factory cannot accept a $scope only a $rootscope. Unfortunately I could not even pass a $rootscope successfully. Do you have an example?

Comment: I don't see why you couldn't pass the scope in as an argument.  However, that may not be a great practice.  It sounds like you may want to look into promises.  There's more information here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22159189/angular-js-in-factory-can-i-access-scope

Comment: Does promises follow .then() promise results down the stack toward the next child promise? I do have chained promises per table load but how would that work? Would each .then().then() return the promise back to the controller or to the next then() statement until they all are finished running ? I think that it will flow to the next then() statement. This will not allow me to update the progressbar