# How to use $scope inside of factory declaration in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, coffeescript, angularjs-scope

**books_ctrl.js.coffee**

```
myApp.factory "Book", ($resource) ->
   $resource("/books/:id", {id: "@id", page: 3})
```

The above factory declaration works fine. Now in order to get my pagination to work I want to include a value from my $scope to the $resource-component. Something along the lines of:

```
myApp.factory "Book", ($resource) ->
   $resource("/books/:id", {id: "@id", page: $scope.currentPage})
```

However this error is returned:

```
ReferenceError: $scope is not defined
```

**Full code: books_ctrl.js.coffee**

```
myApp.factory "Book", ($resource) ->
   $resource("/books/:id", {id: "@id", page: $scope.currentPage}, {})

myApp.controller "BooksCtrl", ($http, $scope, Book) ->
  $scope.init = () ->
    $scope.currentPage = 1
    $scope.getBooks()

  $scope.getBooks = () ->
  Book.query().$promise.then (books) ->
    $scope.books = books

  $scope.setPage = (newPage) ->
    newPage = 1 if newPage < 1
    $scope.currentPage = newPage
    $scope.getBooks()
```

Comment: Possible dup http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22159189/angular-js-in-factory-can-i-access-scope

Comment: It's not the same issue. I try to apply the Angular $resource way of declaring a factory.

Comment: A factory is still a provider and you shouldn't use scope inside of a provider like this because there's no way angular can know what scope you are referring to.  Anything related to a particular scope should probably be passed to your provider as a parameter instead.