# Can not inject factory into angularjs controller

Tags: angularjs

Why is the WizardPageSchoolclassCodesFactory factory not injected? Its always null!

The error in my chrome console is this:

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $scopeProvider <- $scope <- WizardPageSchoolclassCodesFactory



    angular.module('myModule').controller('WizardMainController', function ($scope, WizardPageSchoolclassCodesFactory) {

    // do stuff with data

    });

'use strict';
angular.module('myModule').factory('WizardPageSchoolclassCodesFactory', function($scope) {
        this.getData = function()
        {
            return "hello";
        }
});
```

Comment: Remove injection of `$scope` from factory definition and create an API in the factory.

Comment: Why can I not inject the scope into the factory? I removed the $scope but nothing changed!

Comment: Refer this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22159189/angular-js-in-factory-can-i-access-scope).

Comment: Sorry remove $scope helped, I just got another error which was misleading!

Comment: Your factory is declared like a service. A factory should be a function that returns an object.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass scope into your factory you can do it in this way:

```
app.factory('WizardPageSchoolclassCodesFactory', function() {
    return function(scope){
        this.getData = function()
        {
            scope.test = "test";
            return "hello";
        }
    }
});
```

In controller you have to create new instance of your factory and pass scope in constructor:

```
var factory = new WizardPageSchoolclassCodesFactory($scope);
```

Then you can use declared factory methods:

```
factory.getData();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/aartek/THE4P/

Comment: Surely I do NOT want to bring the $scope outside a controller. I just wanted to know the technical reason why I get an 'exception' doing this...

Comment: This way you are tightly coupling the factory with the controller. Factory should be abstracted from the controller logic. You can send the variable `test` to factory instead of sending the `scope` altogether. Makes sense?

Comment: @dmahapatro you're right, but sometimes passing scope has advantages. For example recently I had to create widgets dashboard - each widget has it own scope and widgets should communicate with each other by sending/receiving events. Instead of repeating same code in each controller, I inject factory with passed scope, and this factory creates listeners for me. It looks like this: http://pastebin.com/xMGZha2v. Instead of writing `scope.$on...` I can simply register listeners to scope by using factory methods.

Comment: Passing controller `scope` in a factory is a bad practice... It is a clear violation of encapsulation IMHO.