# How to set $scope.property only when corresponding value is defined/resolved

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

Inside my controller I have this piece of code:

```
$scope.property = localStorageService.get('property');
```

To clarify, [localStorageService](https://github.com/grevory/angular-local-storage) is an angular module which helps deal with setting and getting Local Storage variables.

The problem is `localStorageService.get('property')` will only be set after a certain period of time because of an asynchronous $http call handled by a factory class. At the time when I do the assignment, localStorageService.get('property') is undefined, but will eventually be resolved by the xhr call.

```
App.factory('fact', ['$http', 'localStorageService', function($http, localStorageService){
    return {
        fetchProperty: function() {
            $http.get('/property')
                .success(function(data, status, headers, config){
                    localStorageService.set('property', data);
                })
        }
    }
}]);
```

How do I set `$scope.property` when and only when `localStorageService.get('property')` has already been set?

**edit**

I am using the browser's Local Storage because the retrieved property is meant to persist throughout the application until the user logs out, in which case, it is removed from the browser.

Comment: You should instead return promise from your method and chain it though and set $scope property.

Comment: I'm new to promises. Would you mind showing me code for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As suggested in the comments, return the promise. You can even chain the `then` calls like this

```
return $http.get('/property').then(function(data) {
    localStorageService.set('property', data);
    return data;
});
```

Then, in your controller...

```
fact.fetchProperty().then(function(property) {
    $scope.property = property;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the [bind function](https://github.com/grevory/angular-local-storage#bind) of local storage service.

Something like

`App.factory('fact', ['$scope', '$http', 'localStorageService', function($scope, $http, localStorageService){
    return {
        fetchProperty: function() {
            $http.get('/property')
                .success(function(data, status, headers, config){
                    localStorageService.set('property', data);
                    localStorageService.bind($scope, 'property');
                })
        }
    }
}]);`

Then you shouldn't need to set the value in your controller.

Comment: You never see `$scope` injected into factories. Which `$scope` is it?

Comment: you're right @Phil there shouldn't be a scope in factory, my bad. http://stackoverflow.com/a/22159243/3745378 Your answer is the better one.