# When to call $scope.apply() for webservice callbacks

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, web-services

I am currently developing an Angular JS project where in I call a webservice and then in the success callback update a textbox value based on the result.

Now, my webservice gets called a bit late and the success callback takes some time. In the success callback I have updated a textbox value as well as hidden a loading progress dialog.

However the progress dialog is never  hidden and textbox is not updated if I don't use `$scope.apply()`.

If the use the same, it gets applied. What is the purpose of `$scope.apply()`.

What are the best practices of using it. Can it be used in situations like mine. I have also tried using `$timeout` . Even that works but I don't think its a preferred approach.

Here is my code

//the service implementation

```
app.service('registerService', function ($http, APP_CONFIG, $q, spinnerService) {
this.callService = function (request) {
    spinnerService.show('mySpinner')
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: APP_CONFIG.baseUrl + '/register',
        data: request
    }).success(function (data) {
        deferred.resolve(data);
    }).error(function () {
        deferred.reject('There was an error while making request');
    });
    return deferred.promise;
  };
 });
```

//calling the service from inside the controller

```
 registerService.callService(JSON.stringify(requestData)).then(function (data) {
       $scope.$apply(function () {
      spinnerService.hide('mySpinner');//hide loading..this works!
    });

      spinnerService.hide('mySpinner');//hide loading ..this does not if I remove $scope.apply()

    }, function () {
      //unable to fetch NLS resource
      spinnerService.hide('mySpinner');//hide loading
    });


}
```

//spinner service implemtation

```
app.factory('spinnerService', function () {
    var cache = {};
    return {

// A private function intended for spinner directives to register themselves with the service.
_register: function (spinnerScope) {
  // If no id is passed in, throw an exception.
  if (!spinnerScope.id) {
    throw new Error("A spinner must have an ID to register with the spinner service.");
  }

  // Add our spinner directive's scope to the cache.
  cache[spinnerScope.id] = spinnerScope;
},

// A private function exposed just in case the user really needs to manually unregister a spinner.
_unregister: function (spinnerId) {
  delete cache[spinnerId];
},

// A private function that will remove an entire spinner group if needed.
_unregisterGroup: function (group) {
  for (var spinnerId in cache) {
    if (cache.hasOwnProperty(spinnerId)) {
      if (cache[spinnerId].group === group) {
        delete cache[spinnerId];
      }
    }
  }
},

// A private function that will clear out all spinners from the cache.
_unregisterAll: function () {
  for (var spinnerId in cache) {
    if (cache.hasOwnProperty(pinnerId)) {
      delete cache[spinnerId];
    }
  }
},

// Show the specified spinner.
// If loadingText is specified, replace the loadingText specified on the directive as we show the spinner.
show: function (spinnerId, loadingText) {

  $("body").find("#loading").addClass("mydiv");
  if (cache.hasOwnProperty(spinnerId)) {
    var spinnerScope = cache[spinnerId];
    spinnerScope.showSpinner = true;
    if (loadingText !== undefined) {
      spinnerScope.loadingText = loadingText;
    }

  }
},

// Hide the specified spinner.
// If doneText is specified, replace the doneText specified on the directive as we hide the spinner.
hide: function (spinnerId, doneText) {

  if (cache.hasOwnProperty(spinnerId)) {
    var spinnerScope = cache[spinnerId];
    $("body").find("#loading").removeClass("mydiv");
    spinnerScope.showSpinner = false;

    if (doneText !== undefined) {
      spinnerScope.doneText = doneText;
    }

  }
}

};
```

});

Comment: Shouldn't have to use `$apply()` for a callback triggered from within angular... and why wrap `$http` in a promise? It returns a promise anyway. - maybe read https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http and clean up the code to follow best practice and your problem may go away.

Comment: If I don't explicitly return a promise then how will the control move back to my controller from where I can update my $scope or any UI stufff?

Comment: Just make your callService `return $http(...)` and controller will deal with it fine.

Comment: There is a basic problem in your code that you are trying to cache the scope objects and then trying to update scope inside your factory, This is not considered a good practice, You should try to do something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22159243/572799

Comment: ok @NarainMittal. I get your point. then can you tell me in which conditions is $scope.apply() used and why?

Comment: Typically you won't need to manually call $apply() as long as you are doing your stuff in angular context. Over here you are trying to cache the scope variables inside your factory and then updating, which doesn't trigger the digest cycle to update the model. If instead you return some kind of a flag from the factory and update the scope accordingly in your .then() callback, you won't need to call $apply(). It will be called automatically