# ionic factory not open other url

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic-view

i have an ionic modal that have button to allow user open other page
while this modal have jrcrop

my sample

```
angular.module('ionicApp', ['ionic']).controller('cropCtrl', function($http,$scope, $ionicModal, $jrCrop) {
        $jrCrop.crop({
          url: 'img.jpg',
          width: 200,
          height: 200,
        })
        .then(function(canvas) {
          $ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl('result-cropped.html', function(modal) {
            $scope.modal = modal;

            modal.show().then(function() {
              document.querySelector('.cropped-canvas').appendChild(canvas);
            });
          });
        });

    }).factory("$jrCrop",["$ionicModal","$rootScope","$q",function(t,i,e)

{..........................
,openpage:function(){$scope.go('images');}
...................
    }]);
```

and i have error says

$scope is not defined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is undefined because you never defined it:

```
factory("$jrCrop",["$ionicModal","$rootScope","$q",function(t,i,e)
```

But you don't even want to use `$scope` inside a factory. You would access whatever is needed from the factory inside a controller which has access to `$scope`.

Look at this stack: [Accessing $scope in AngularJS factory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22159189/accessing-scope-in-angularjs-factory)

Also: You write `$scope.go('images');` as if it should be `$state.go('images');` unless you have a `$scope` function called `go()`. **But**, again you shouldn't be using either of those in the factory.