# Using a function within a function in same factory and passing $scope (AngularJS)

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am making a factory with multiple functions. Structure is like following:

```
app.factory('Service', function() {

    var Service = {};
        Service.method1 = function($scope) {
        //logic
        return something1
        };
        Service.method2 = function($scope) {
        return something2
        };
        Service.method3 = function($scope) {
        return something3
        };
        Service.method4 = function($scope, Service) {
        var object1 = Service.method1($scope)
        var object2 = Service.method2($scope)
        var object3 = Service.method3($scope)

        //do something with object 1,2,3 and return the result
        return result
        };
```

Is this a right way of using a function in a factory inside other function in a factory? And I'm not sure whether I can just pass $scope like that.

Comment: Does this work for you? Are you getting any errors or anything? Take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/22159189/1887101

Comment: Generally you don't want to use scope in your service.  $scope binds data to the view, which is the job of the controller.  The service should just handle data for the controller to use, just as results from a $http request.

Comment: The code works only where the data lives which is controller1. But when I use this service in controller2, it does not work. Is there a way to persist the data within the service? I know it's not a good practice to pass $scope, but all my data lives in it so I'm not sure what is the best way

Comment: Services are singletons so the data will persist once it's assigned.  I created a fiddle example here: https://jsfiddle.net/koa23fb5/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Answer for Question 1**

You can call an internal service function from `self`

```
var moduleA= angular.module('A',[]);
moduleA.factory('Service', function() {
    var self = this;
    self.method1: function() {
            alert('a');
        },
    self.method2: function() {
            self.method1();
        } 
    };
});
```

Then you can call your factory service like this

```
angular.module('B',['A']).controller('BCtrl',function($scope,'Service'){
    Service.method2();
});
```

**Answer for Question 2**

A service should not change any `$scope`. You don't typically use `$scope` inside a factory, service or provider. However, you can inject `$rootScope` dependency in the factory's function constructor and use it.

```
module.factory( 'Service', function($rootScope){
    $rootScope.value = "value";
});
```

Comment: can you provide more info on self and this? do I name self as my service name? or is it literally self and this?

Answer (score 0):

Factories need to **return** the service object. Persistent data is declared as `var`'s in the factory function.

```
app.factory('Service', function() {

    //Declare persistant data here
    var persistantData;

    var Service = {};

    Service.method1 = function(arg) {
        //logic
        return something1;
    };
    Service.method2 = function(arg) {
        return something2;
    };

    //return service object
    return Service;
};
```

USAGE:

```
app.controller('ctrl1', function($scope, Service) {
    $scope.out1 = Service.method1($scope.in1);
});
```

Anything stored in persistent data will last the entire lifetime of the app.