# App is breaking due to factory in angularjs. Why?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have no idea why this code is breaking...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>TEST</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js">     </script>

  <script>
    var app = angular.module('test', []);
    app.service('mySerivce', function($scope) {
      return 0;
    });
    app.controller('myController', function($scope, myService) {
    });

  </script>

</head>
<body ng-app='test'>
  <div ng-controller="myController">
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I am getting the error message:

`Error: [$injector:unpr]` http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.6/$injector/unpr?p0=myServiceProvider%20%3C-%20myService%20%3C-%20myController

Comment: `mySerivce` != `myService`

Comment: ... and after you fix that problem, `$scope` isn't available to services or factories.

Comment: I'm confused. I was typing that up. Even after changing mySerivce to myService, it still isn't working.

Comment: When something is not working, you almost always get an exact error message. It is not just "not working".

Comment: angular.js:10287Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.6/$injector/unpr?p0=%24scopeProvider%20%3C-%20%24scope%20%3C-%20myService
    at Error (native)

Comment: Did you even read the comment of Phil?

Comment: Ah I see! I just deleted $scope and figured out the answer. I never knew $scope is not available to factories or services.

Comment: `$scope` is only available to controllers and directives. Also, the function passed to the `.service` provider should be a constructor function, ie it shouldn't return anything

Comment: please read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22159189/accessing-scope-in-angularjs-factory if you not getting  @Phil point

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Accessing $scope in AngularJS factory?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22159189/accessing-scope-in-angularjs-factory)

Answer (score 0):

$scope is not available to factories or services. Also I misspelled myService.

Answer (score 0):

Add controller dependency in string array format, like below:

```
.controller('MyController', ['myService', function (myService) {
}]);
```

You can refer this in [Error: [$injector:unpr]](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/unpr)