# AngularJS : Getting Error on adding $scope in factory-service

Tags: javascript, angularjs

studentService.js

```
   app.factory('saveStudentService',['$http','$scope',function ($http,$scope) { 
            var studentData = {};
            studentData.save = function(jsondata){
                var action = "student";
                var method = "POST";
                $http({
                    url: action,
                    method: method,
                    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
                    data: jsondata
                }).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                    toastr.success(status +' : Data has been submitted successfully ');
                }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                    toastr.error(status + ' : Data has not been submitted successfully ');
                });
            };
            return studentData;
        }]);
```

I am getting this error

```
angular.js:13642Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.6/$injector/unpr?p0=%24scopeProvider%20%3C-%20%24scope%20%3C-%20saveStudentService
    at Error (native)
    at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js:6:412
```

If from studentService.js, $scope is being removed, i.e

```
app.factory('saveStudentService',['$http',function ($http) {
```

this code is working properly, and not getting any error message in console.

Following is the studentController.js file from where this studentService is being called.

StudentController.js

```
app.controller('saveStudentCtrl',['$scope', 'saveStudentService', function($scope,saveStudentService) { 
    $scope.submit_create_student = function() {
        var jsondata = $scope.student;
        saveStudentService.save(jsondata);
    }

}]);
```

but if same thing i.e $scope is being added in the updateStudentService then this code is working as expected.

```
app.controller('updateStudentCtrl',['$scope','retriveStudentService', 'updateStudentService', function($scope,retriveStudentService, updateStudentService) {    
    $scope.getStudentDataFromServer = function() {      
        retriveStudentService.get();
    };
    $scope.submit_update_student = function(e) {
        updateStudentService.update();
    }

}]);
```

Could someone please clarify, what is happening here. Though able to use same thing in one place, but not able to use same process at someother place.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Accessing $scope in AngularJS factory?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22159189/accessing-scope-in-angularjs-factory)

Comment: you mean to say in studentController.js and studentService.js ?

Comment: But why do you need $scope in factory? IMO there is something wrong in design if you need scope in your factory/service

Comment: thanks for your suggestion :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot inject scope into services. You can inject it to controllers.

Comment: hey thanks for your comment. I have just started working with angularjs.

Comment: from my code if you find something else that need to be rectified, please let me know.. thanks

Comment: Your code looks good, try using $resource instead of $http when possible.

Comment: Yes, you don't inject $scope into services.  Sometimes you would inject $rootScope into a service if for example it needs to broadcast system-wide events.  Services are designed to be global objects, while $scope is designed to hold contextual data.